# How to close vertical bars in table

Tags: tables

Does anyone know how to fix the vertical bar on the right side? Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.15\linewidth}||p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.2\linewidth}| p{0.2\linewidth}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Project Timeline} \\
 \hline
Family & First Examples Computed By&All Examples Computed By&Conjectures Proposed By & Proof Completed By\\
 \hline
 $I$ is funny  & June 2021    &October 2021&   December 2022 &   May 2022 (if possible)\\
 \hline\\
blah blah blah or $5$  & September 2021    &November 2021&   January 2021 &   May 2022 (if possible)\\
\hline\\
$I$ is angry  & October 2021    &December 2021&   February 2022 &   May 2022 (if possible)\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Table!]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Remove rows terminators `\\ ` after `\hline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you should not use `\hline\\` but only `\hline`.

Some off-topic remarks about your table. You not provide any information about your document layout nor how this table is inserted in it. Anyway, see, if the following rewriting of your table is of some help to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
                       \hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L{0.85}||L{0.85}|L{0.85}|L{1.225}|L{1.225}|} \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Project Timeline} \\
 \hline
Family & First Examples Computed By & All Examples Computed By & Conjectures Proposed By & Proof Completed By\\
 \hline
 $I$ is funny  & June 2021    &October 2021&   December 2022 &   May 2022 (if possible)\\
 \hline
blah blah blah or $5$  & September 2021    &November 2021&   January 2021 &   May 2022 (if possible)\\
\hline
$I$ is angry  & October 2021    &December 2021&   February 2022 &   May 2022 (if possible)\\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Now the table width is equal to `\textwidth` independent from it size (yours is not), text in cells is not justified but (smart by use of the `ragged2e` package) left aligned by new defined column type (which enable simple changing ratio between cells width, however, their sum had to be integer equal to number of columns).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will take be sure to provide information on my document layout next time!

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen, you are welcome! However, since answer solve your problem you may consider to0 accept my answer by clicking on the check mark at top left sise of my answer!